# Integrating QT with CMAKE in Mac OS

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to integrate my QT project to my CLION project. 
In this case I am having problems with the CMAKE and QT integration.
The content of my CmakeList.txt is:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(BD2_PROYECTO_1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/Users/jonathanprieto/Qt5.13.0/5.13.0/")

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

add_executable(BD2_PROYECTO_1 parser.cpp parser.h main.cpp statichashing.cpp statichashing.h randomfile.cpp randomfile.h record.cpp record.h transactions.cpp transactions.h ui/input.cpp ui/input.h ui/ui_dialog.h ui/mainwindow.h ui/mainwindow.cpp ui/mainwindow.ui ui/ui_input.ui ui/input.h ui/dialog.ui)
target_link_libraries(helloworld Qt5::Widgets)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Could someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a `/Users/jonathanprieto/Qt5.13.0/5.13.0/lib/cmake` ? If so, _that_ should be your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. Also, you can install Qt via `brew` just fine.

Comment: Unrelated: `find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)` allows you to specify multiple components at once, should you need it.

Comment: I don´t have a lib directory, only clang_64, ios, src, and many versions of android.

Comment: I found the solution ! The path was: /Users/jonathanprieto/Qt5.13.0/5.13.0/clang_64/lib/cmake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some tries, I found the solution to my problem.
So I am posting my CMakeList.txt code in case you have the same problem.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(BD2_PROYECTO_1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/Users/jonathanprieto/Qt5.13.0/5.13.0/clang_64/lib/cmake")

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

add_executable(BD2_PROYECTO_1 parser.cpp parser.h main.cpp statichashing.cpp statichashing.h randomfile.cpp randomfile.h record.cpp record.h transactions.cpp transactions.h ui/input.cpp ui/input.h ui/ui_dialog.h ui/mainwindow.h ui/mainwindow.cpp ui/mainwindow.ui ui/ui_input.ui ui/input.h ui/dialog.ui ui/input.ui)
target_link_libraries(BD2_PROYECTO_1 Qt5::Widgets)
```

I hope this will helpful for you.